# E1101 (no-member) for code that works well

Tags: python, object, oop, constructor, pylint

I have a structure similar to below, in my code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(
            self,
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )
            self.matrix = self._get_matrix()

class B(A):
    def __init__(
            self,
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )
        super().__init__(
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )

    def _get_matrix(self):
        <DO SOMETHING>

class C(A):
    def __init__(
            self,
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )
        super().__init__(
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )

    def _get_matrix(self):
        <DO SOMETHING>
```

The code works fine. However, Pylint returns an `E1101(no-member)` error. How can I change my code so I don't get this error?

The `_get_matrix()` methods in classes B and C work differently, so I cannot place them in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark A as abstract base class using abc module, then add method signature of `_get_matrix` to A.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    def __init__(
            self,
            <SOME_VARIABLES>
            )
            self.matrix = self._get_matrix()
    @abstractmethod
    def _get_matrix(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```